# Error reading character of string C++

Tags: c++, null

I showed my codes and i have an error reading character of string. Everything is okey in my debugger until the `NULL`.

```
*Warning    C4715   `String::equas`: not all control paths return a value*
```

I can not use it because I am using a `NULL` pointer for the parameter.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Header:

```
class String
{
public:

    String();

    bool empty();        

    String(char * other_str);

    bool equals(const String other_str);

private:

    char* m_str;

};
```

My Codes:

```
#include "String.hpp"
#include <string>
#include<iostream>


int my_len(const char* p) {
    int c = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        c++;
        *p++;
    }
    return c;
}



String::String()
    :m_str(NULL)
{
}

String::String(char * other_str)
{
}

bool String::empty()
{
    return true;
}

bool String::equals(const String other_str)
{
    if (m_str == NULL && other_str.m_str == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
if (m_str == NULL && other_str.m_str != NULL) {
    return false;
}

if (m_str != NULL && other_str.m_str == NULL) {
    return false;
}

if (m_str != NULL && other_str.m_str != NULL) {

    int mystrlen = my_len(m_str);
    int myrhslen = my_len(other_str.m_str);

    if (mystrlen != myrhslen)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mystrlen; i++)
        {
            if (m_str[i] != other_str.m_str[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

i will add this codes:

```
   int mylen(const char* p) {

        int c = 0;
        while (*p != '\0')
        {
            c++;
            *p++;
        }
        return c;
    }


    void my_cpy(char dest, const char* src) {

        int i = 0;
        while (src[i] != '\0') {
            dest[i] = src[i];
            i++;
        }
        dest[i] = '\0';
    }


    char mytrdup(const char *s) {    
        char* d = (char*)malloc((my_len(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));        
        if (d == NULL) {
            return NULL;            
        }           
        else{
        my_cpy(d, s);       
        }                       
        return d;                           

    }
```

Comment: Real code, practice.

Comment: I edited and added about TEST_TRUE.

Comment: your function equals doesn't return value at all possible paths. You need to add return statement at the end

Comment: @ useruser1438832  Okey thank you, i will change write to public.

Comment: @ Prabu Thank you, i think i have to add return false to end of the codes? But i think i have to do something for constructor?

Comment: @user1438832 what the problem with accessibg private member of the class from member function of the **same class**?

Comment: Sorry there is no problem in accessing private member in same class.

Comment: @user1438832 Okey, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `String empty_string2(NULL);`

This will invokde the constructor version :

> `String::String(char* other_str) {}`

which does nothing, leaving the `m_str` pointer dangling/uninitialized. You should change this constructor somehow, either by copying the string and setting the `m_str` pointer accordingly, or by setting `m_str` to the same address as the parameter. Either case it depends on what you want to achieve.

Besides, many other problems exist in your code. I notice already this one in you *implemented* function `my_len`. you should change `*p++` into `p++`. I wonder how this passed the compilation btw, since the parameter is a `const char*`.

Finally, the compiler's warning is correct and very clear, although it is *not* the source of the problem you are facing *for the time being*.

EDIT: to make a duplicate copy of the string, you can write you constructor like this:

```
String::String(const char* other_str)
{ m_str = (other_str ? strdup(other_str) : other_str); }
```

And besides, preferably use `null_ptr` instead of `NULL` in your code. Since C++11, this is *the* standard for null pointers.

Comment: How can i change this constructor? I tried strdup but it does not work because of NULL parameter. What is your advice?
Also, thank you i will change p++

Comment: @NedimBak see answer in the last Edit.

Comment: I checked and wrote your codes. Thank you so much it is working. But my mentor yesterday said to me " You can't use strdup because you are using a NULL pointer for the parameter.I’m just letting you know that strdup as documented by C++ forums won’t work with NULL and you would need to handle the NULL condition in some other way." 

Do you agree with him?

Comment: @NedimBak yes and no. Yes because you cannot pass a null to `strdup`. No because you can *check* for null before calling it; this is what my code does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can i create my own stdup function? Because it is rule for me, i have to create my own function. I will add to my question please check it. Maybe NULL is problem for my own function. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @NedimBak sure you can, you can find plenty of such implementations on the net.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I add TEST_TRUE and then that work correctly.

Comment: Thank you but to where and how?

Comment: sorry, I didn't copy #define TEST_TRUE(x) printf("Test '%s' %s\n", #x, (x) ? "passed" : "failed!"). So I wrote a new one. But anyway, that still works. And no error.

Comment: What did you do for String::String(const char* other_str) ?

Comment: The "no-error" in your test was because it *happened* that the non-initialized pointer was null. This does not mean that we didin't have *undefined behavior*. The pointer `m_str` **must** be initialized in all constructors, be it to null or to some valid location.